# Phantom phone taps on iphone 10

Tags: iphone

I have a 2 year old iphone 10 - it's never had any major drops or anything, just normal wear and tear. 
In the last week, I've noticed the touchscreen either stops responding to taps or seems to be randomly be picking up taps that I didn't actually initiate. This has caused me to 'accidentally' respond to messages, other annoying mishaps, rendering the phone unusable at time.
Is there a diagnostic I can run or some well know remedy. The screen is clean and free of anything debris.